# Super Adiabatic Evolution numerically

Tags: time-evolution, adiabatic

I'm doing some adiabatic and super adiabatic evolution using python but without success, the super adiabatic to be more precise. The problem is the way I've manage to write the super adiabatic Hamiltonian, it can be written in function of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the Adiabatic Hamiltonian as:

$$ H_{SAD} = \sum_n \left [ E_n|n(t)\rangle\langle n(t)|+\mathrm{i}\hbar\left (|\dot n (t)\rangle \langle n(t)| - \langle n(t)|\dot n (t)\rangle|n(t)\rangle\langle n(t)| \right )\right ]. $$

My two different approaches were a numerical and a symbolic. In the numerical I've created a list of Adiabatic Hamiltonians (so i get one array with this dimensions [ row of Hamiltonian, column of Hamiltonian, time]). The problem in this approach is that I'm not sure how to solve the dynamics of this system that are ruled by the Master Equation:

$$ \dot \rho_{\mathrm{tot}} = -\frac{\mathrm{i}}{\hbar}[H_{\mathrm{tot}}, \rho_{\mathrm{tot}}(t)]. $$

I've found this Python library that solves matrix ODE ([odeintw](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/odeintw)), but a matrix in the shape of mine are not allowed in it, I would need a explicit time dependence to do so:

I've tried to use [mesolve](http://qutip.org/docs/latest/guide/dynamics/dynamics-time.html) from QuTip but the problem is the same, the solver doesn't support a time dependence express as a list of matrices.

This is how I construct my Super Adiabatic Hamiltonian:

```
import numpy as np
from qutip import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from odeintw import odeintw

x,y,z, I = sigmax(), sigmay(), sigmaz(), qeye(2)
l = 3
psi_i = tensor(bell_state('11'),ket('1'))
rho0 = ket2dm(psi_i)

Hi = tensor(x,x,I) + tensor(y,y,I)
#Normalized t, s = t/tau
s = np.linspace(0, 1, 100) 

#Adiabatic Hamiltonian
Had = np.zeros([2**l,2**l,len(s)],dtype=complex)

#Super Adiabatic Hamiltonian
Hsad = np.zeros([2**l,2**l,len(s)],dtype=complex)

#Eigenvectors of Had
n = np.zeros([2**l,2**l,len(s)],dtype=complex) 


#Time derivative of n
dn = np.zeros([2**l,2**l,len(s)],dtype=complex)

#Eigenvalues of Had
E = np.zeros([len(s),2**l],dtype=complex)

i = 0 
for t in s:
    Had[:,:,i] += (1-t)*Hi.full() 
    val, vec = np.linalg.eig(Had[:,:,i])

    
    sort_perm = val.argsort()

    val.sort()     # <-- This sorts the list in place.
    vec = vec[:, sort_perm]


    n[:,:,i] += vec # eigen_i = vec[:,i]
    E[i,:] += val
    i+=1
    
for i in range(len(s)-1):
    dt = s[i+1]-s[i]
    dx = n[:,:,i+1] - n[:,:,i]
    dn[:,:,i] += dx/dt

nn = np.zeros([2**l,2**l,len(s)],dtype=complex)
Enn = np.zeros([2**l,2**l,len(s)],dtype=complex)
dnn = np.zeros([2**l,2**l,len(s)],dtype=complex)
theta = np.zeros([len(s)],dtype=complex)
thtnn = np.zeros([2**l,2**l,len(s)],dtype=complex)
for i in range(len(s)-1):
    for j in range(2**l):
        Enn[:,:,i] += E[i,j]*np.outer(n[:,j,i],np.conjugate(n[:,j,i]))
        dnn[:,:,i] += np.outer(dn[:,j,i],np.conjugate(n[:,j,i]))
    
        theta[i] += np.dot(np.conjugate(n[:,j,i]),dn[:,j,i])
        nn[:,:,i] += np.outer(n[:,j,i],np.conjugate(n[:,j,i]))
        thtnn[:,:,i]+= (theta[i])*nn[:,:,i]


Hsad = Enn +1j*(dnn -thtnn)
```

In the analytical approach I've used SymPy. The problem here is to convert the symbolic expression I've founded to some that are possible to use as input to QuTip or odeintw.

but I have no idea on how to use it to solve my problem or if its possible. Can some one help me please?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to approximate your time-dependent Hamiltonian by a piecewise-constant Hamiltonian. Divide your time interval up into finite timesteps, and call odeintw or mesolve once for each step. The initial condition for step $i$ is $\rho$ at the end of step $i-1$.

Comment: But my Hamiltonian is already written in that form. What I having trouble is to make odeintw understand that for each time step it needs to use one specific Hamiltonian form the list I've gave it

Comment: Call odeintw, using only the first Hamiltonian in the list, with $\rho_0$ as the initial condition. The result will be some matrix $\rho_1$. Now call odeintw with only the second Hamiltonian in the list, and give $\rho_1$ as the initial condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem with qutip meSolve. Read this link to know how to handle time-dependents ones.
http://qutip.org/docs/latest/guide/dynamics/dynamics-time.html

Read part 2 & 3  :

1-**String based**: The Hamiltonian and/or collapse operators are expressed as a list of [qobj, string] pairs, where the time-dependent coefficients are represented as strings. The resulting Hamiltonian is then compiled into C code using Cython and executed.

2   -**Array Based**: The Hamiltonian and/or collapse operators are expressed as a list of [qobj, np.array] pairs. The arrays are 1 dimensional and dtype are complex or float. They must contain one value for each time in the tlist given to the solver. Cubic spline interpolation will be used between the given times.

Comment: "Like the previous method, the string-based format uses a list pair format `[Op, str]` where str is now a string representing the time-dependent coefficient. For our first example, this string would be `9 * exp(-(t / 5.) ** 2)`. The Hamiltonian in this format would take the form:

`In [42]: H = [H0, [H1, '9 * exp(-(t / 5) ** 2)']]`".

This is different form my Hamiltonian, there is a explicit time dependence that I don't have

Comment: And in Array Based, I not sure how to use in my problem. Do I need to interpolate all 64 components of my Hamiltonian? In the example were used `In [55]: S = Cubic_Spline(t[0], t[-1], noisy_data)` and them `H = [H0, [H1, S]]` but in my problem I don't have a constant matrix times a function of t, so how do I use it in my problem?

Comment: @lfcmoraes please write an example similar to your hamiltonian

Comment: I put the code to generate the Hamiltonian as a list

Comment: @lfcmoraes nice¡ pay attention that if you have a lot of process in this list after the generation ,you should use Double in your input because you might see some seesaws in your results. If you have dissipation part ,you should do the same.

Comment: @lfcmoraes if you use function instead of “for” you’ll get your results rapidly

Comment: @lfcmoraes if you generate rho0 for meSolve it doesn’t need to do that

Comment: What is Double? Double precision?

Comment: @lfcmoraes yes.double precision.

Comment: But I still have no idea o how to use my Hamiltonian on mesolve

Comment: @lfcmoraes you should just put the list name in H part of meSolve . Whats the problem¿ if you get steps error you should set option manually.

Comment: When I tried `result = mesolve(Hsad,rho0, t,options=options)` I get, `----> 1 result = mesolve(Hsad,rho0, t,options=options)
      2 # rho_t = result.states

/qutip/mesolve.py in mesolve(H, rho0, tlist, c_ops, e_ops, args, options, progress_bar, _safe_mode)
    256         ss = _mesolve_func_td(H, c_ops, rho0, tlist, args, options)
    257     else:
--> 258         raise Exception("Invalid H type")
    259 
    260     func, ode_args = ss.makefunc(ss, rho0, args, e_ops, options)

Exception: Invalid H type`

Comment: First you should right as mesolve(Hsad,psi0,t,[],[],{}) because the mesolve function should get the inputs and if you don’t have all of them put like mine. After that for t you should define your time steps and range as np.linspace(initialTime,finalTime,steps).your steps must be equal to your hamiltonian list size.and check the type of your Hsad .probably you have some mistake in your Hsad list

Comment: What should I put on [] and {}? And I set time using np.linspace() exactly as you proposed

Comment: @lfcmoraes nothing if you don’t have dissipation .just null [] and {}

Comment: Check that your Hsad is list of qobj

Comment: @lfcmoraes what is your error now then¿

Comment: Apparently worked, now the error is in solving the ODE `Exception: ODE integration error: Try to increase the allowed number of substeps by increasing the nsteps parameter in the Options class.`. Thanks

Comment: @lfcmoraes befor meSolve add “options =options(nsteps=1000000) or any number you need. And in change your meSolve to mesolve(H,psi,t,[],[],{},options=options)